# Problema con UPDATE en PHP

Tags: pdo, update

Tengo un inconveniente con un UPDATE. No entiendo el motivo por el cual no me actualiza el valor. Debe ser algún error muy bobo y no lo puedo encontrar, agradecería que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Explico, tengo una tabla que al cumplir ciertas condiciones se actualice su puntaje. Pero cuando las cumple el valor no cambia .

```
    try {
    $add = "UPDATE calculo SET puntaje_fecha=:puntaje_fecha WHERE id_calculo=:id_calculo";
    $d = $conn->prepare($add);
    $d->bindParam(':puntaje_fecha', $_POST['puntaje_fecha']);
    $d->bindParam(':id_calculo', $_POST['id_calculo']);
$d->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
}
```

?>

La consulta la hago en la misma pagina

```
  <body>


  <form action="actualizar.php" action="post">
  <?php foreach ($pr as $p){ $s=0;?>
  <?php if ((($p['id_fecha'])==($r['id_fecha']))&&(($r['id_fecha'])==($f['numero_fecha']))&&(($r['id_fecha'])==($c['nFecha']))&&(($p['id_usuario'])==($c['id_us']))){

    if(($p['valorL1'] == $r['valorL1']) && ($p['valorV1'] == $r['valorV1'])) {
       $s= ($s+3);
     } elseif(($p['valorL1'] > $r['valorV1']) && ($p['valorL1'] > $p['valorV1'])) {
       $s= ($s+1);
     }  elseif(($p['valorL1'] < $r['valorV1']) && ($p['valorL1'] < $p['valorV1'])) {
       $s= ($s1);
     }  elseif(($p['valorL1'] == $r['valorV1']) && ($p['valorL1'] == $p['valorV1']) && ($r['valorL1'] <> $p['valorL1'])) {
       $s= ($s+1);
     }  else {
       $s= ($s+0);
     }?>
     <input type="hidden" name="puntaje_fecha" value="<?php echo $s; ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="id_calculo" value="<?php echo $c['id_calculo']; ?>">

  <?php }} ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Actualiza puntos">
</form>
```

La condicional que se muestra ahí es muy larga de explicar pero lo importante es que se cumple y me realiza la suma que yo necesito, el problema es pasar el valor para actualizarlo

[image: BDD]

Al inspeccionar el codigo fuente puedo ver que la suma se realiza porque da 3, osea, la condicion se cumple

[image: inspeccion]

Agradecería cualquier ayuda, saludos!

Comment: ¿Tu formulario crea los input hidden dentro del foreach? Si es así, tienes N elementos con el mismo identificador. De paso, procura identificar los elementos con un atributo `id` único

Comment: Si, necesito que sea dentro del foreach porque recorre array de otra tabla. Les asigno el identificador pero el problema persiste

Comment: Si el update lo haces tomando del POST el valor con el atributo `name`, va a seguir el mismo problema. Actualiza la pregunta si actualizaste el código.

Comment: Disculpa, habia entendido mal tu primer respuesta. No he cambiado nada del codigo, le habia agregado un id a cada input, eso habia entendido jaja. Igualmente sigo sin poder resolverlo.

Comment: `$d->execute()` parece faltar después de `bindParam` para realizar la ejecución de la consulta.

Comment: Ahi lo actualice, probé con el $d->execute() para que corra la consulta pero nada ocurre

Comment: Imprime el contenido de $_POST cuando envías la petición (`print_r()`) para saber con qué esta trabajando el armado de la consulta.

Comment: Al querer imprimir para ver que trabaja con el POST me dice que las dos variables con las que trabajo en el update no estan definidas. Eso me desconcierta

Comment: Es `method="post"` y no `action="post"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es `method="post"` y no `action="post"` como tienes puesto en el código.

Por culpa de eso, no tienes un método correcto en el formulario y se utiliza el método por defecto que es GET. Por eso las variables te llegan como indefinidas. Entonces cambia esta línea

```
<form action="actualizar.php" action="post">
```

a esto:

```
<form action="actualizar.php" method="post">
```

y ya te debería funcionar (al menos eso debería hacer que recibieras las variables de forma correcta).

Comment: Jajaja muchas gracias! Increible error bobo he cometido. Saludos!